# Cut lines using Notepad++ Regexp replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to cut lines that have 6 or more characters, hyphen, then other characters or symbols. Hyphen and rest of line should be removed. Source text:

```
0402CS-2
0402CS-3
0402
7812-C
0603CS-1
0603CS-2
0603CS-3
```

As a result, I need this:

```
0402CS
0402CS
0402
7812-C
0603CS
0603CS
0603CS
```

To do that, I use Notepad++ regexp replace feature. Find pattern: **^([^\-]{6,})\-.+$** Replace pattern: **\1**
But there is no option "multiline", so, symbols "^" and "$" doesn't match ONLY beginning and end of the line and actually I have result:

```
0402CS
0402CS
0402
7812  <-- that's wrong!
0603CS
0603CS
0603CS
```

Please advice me how to fix find pattern? Or, maybe there is other handful and powerful free text editor that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the `[^-]` character class also matches a newline.

Add `\n` to it:

```
^([^\n-]{6,})-.+$
```

See [the regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/T1l1Mz/1) (note the `m` multiline modifier (making `^` match the start of the line, and `$` - the end of the line) and `g` modifier (enabling search for multiple occurrences) that is ON by default in Notepad++).

Note that escaping the hyphen is not necessary inside a character class when it is at the start/end of the class, and you never need to escape the hyphen outside the character class.

[image]

Comment: All is ok, great thanks for solution and useful advices!

Answer (score 3):

```
^([^\n\-]{6,})\-.+$

    ^^
```

Just use `\n` as due to `[^-]` the regex can traverse to line below as use that line to make a match.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/BHO93c/1

for the input

`0402
7812-C` the regex matches both lines as `1` line and makes a match.
See demo if `0402` is not there.

https://regex101.com/r/BHO93c/2